# JAVA fx sorting combobox values

Tags: java, mysql, combobox, javafx

I have a combobox cboTEST with values inside for example:

- U7A
- U4B
- U6C
- U1Z
- U7B

The first letter is always going to be "U"..

I want to sort my combobox first on the second number and lastly alphabeticly:

**solution results:**

- U1Z
- U4B
- U6C
- U7A
- U7B
- U9R

How can I do this?

**EDIT:**
this is my method where I fill up my combobox with values from database select statement:

```
private void getData() {
       DataDB db = new DataDB();

       try{
           ArrayList<DataBag> dataList= db.searchData(); //select * from ..
           for(DataBag data : dataList) {
              String name= data.getName();
              cboPloegen.getItems().add(name);    
           }

       } catch (ApplicationException ae) {
      } catch (DBException ae) {
     }
   }
```

Comment: Using [`Collections.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) on the list which you will be using as the items of the ComboBox, should sort out your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the items to the combobox, ensure that they are already sorted.
If your strings to be compared use the natural comparison of Strings in Java (as it seems by your example), then you can just use (as stated in the comment by ItachiUchiha):

```
ObservableList<String> list = ...;
Collections.sort(list);
cboTEST.setItems(list);
```

However, if your items to sort do not implement `Comparable` or the natural ordering does not fit your needs, then you have to use a `Comparator`:

```
private void getData() {
   DataDB db = new DataDB();

   try{
       ArrayList<DataBag> dataList= db.searchData(); //select * from ..
       Collections.sort(dataList, getComparator());

       for (DataBag data : dataList) {
          String name= data.getName();
          cboPloegen.getItems().add(name);    
       }

   } catch (ApplicationException ae) {
   } catch (DBException ae) {
 }
```

}

The `getComparator()` method should look like

```
    private static Comparator<DataBag> getComparator() {
        return new Comparator<DataBag>() {
           @Override
           public int compare(DataBag o1, DataBag o2) {
               String name = o1.getName();
               String name2 = o2.getName();

               // ordering is the natural String ordering in your example
               return name.compareTo(name2); 
           }
    };
}
```

Comment: I'v added my method where I put data in my combobox. Could you take a quick look?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! this was 100% correct! thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Would you mind voting up this answer :)